# How I can map two or one values readed from input

Tags: python-3.x

I try to solve some challange on hackerrank. And description is like follow: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element
So I try this code

```
query,number=map(int,input().split())
```

This code work well when I have exactly two variable and fails when I have one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some input validation before you start processing it if you expect the users to sometimes not enter the expected values, for example:

```
user_input = input().split()
if len(user_input) < 2:
    print("At least two parameters are required!")
else:
    try:
        query = int(user_input[0])
        number = int(user_input[1])
    except ValueError:
        print("At least two integer parameters are required!")
```

You can do even more post-input validation to match your required parameters, or you can combine some aspects of the validation to pick one argument when only one is passed while setting the second argument to the default, etc. It all depends on your desired business logic.

Comment: I think python have shorthands like nextInt as in Java before that.